# smtpException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net

here is the code.

```
void sendMail()
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.To.Add("abc@gmail.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com", txt_name.Text);
    mail.Subject = txt_subject.Text;
    mail.Body = txt_body.Text;

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;

    NetworkCredential yetki = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "11111111");
    smtp.Credentials = yetki;

    smtp.Send(mail);

    Response.Write("mailiniz başarılı bir şekilde gönderilmiştir");
}

protected void btn_gonder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sendMail();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicating it is unhandled means you didn't catch the exception.  Now what you actually do in the catch block to handle the exception is up to you, such as logging it to a file, queuing a retry, or showing a message box.  Or trying to do something to prevent the exception in the first place.

```
protected void btn_gonder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try{
    sendMail();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {

  }
}
```

Also note you can access ex.Message to see the exception message, or add a break point to the catch block and inspect ex.  It is possible there is more you need to do to get it to work with gmail because of the requirements for authentication.  I don't know if the network credentials are enough.  I've always had trouble with it and resorted to using my ISP's email account that doens't require authentication.

Comment: @gmcalab Because it is framework code.  I would only put it inside sendMail if I planned to take some definitive action that would correct the error and successfully complete the call to sendMail, or I planned to rethrow a more specialized exception.  If I am just displaying a message box I want it outside of the reuseable portions of code.  I wouldn't want to call sendMail from a service and have it try to display a message box the user will never see.

Comment: @gmcalab I mean really, the whole point was just to show him a try/catch.  The topic of where to put the try/catch and what to actually do in the catch will vary vastly depending on the context of where he is using this code.  You are narrow minded to think there is a one solution fits all approach.

Comment: @gmcalab FYI I gave your solution an upvote because I believe it is just as valid as my solution.  Again, where the try/catch goes is splitting hairs because it is a discussion that could be very vast and beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 6):

Use a try/catch block

```
void sendMail() {

   try{
      MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

      mail.To.Add("abc@gmail.com");

      mail.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com", txt_name.Text);

      mail.Subject = txt_subject.Text;

      mail.Body = txt_body.Text;

      SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

      smtp.EnableSsl = true;

      NetworkCredential yetki = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "11111111");
      smtp.Credentials = yetki;

      smtp.Send(mail);
      Response.Write("mailiniz başarılı bir şekilde gönderilmiştir");
   }
   catch(Exception e){
      Response.Write(e.Message);
   }

}
```

Comment: i changed my code. but it still gives error and message dont send abc@gmail.com

Comment: So, now you need to tell us what the real error message is, instead of the one in your title.

Answer (score 2):

You add a try/catch block to your code and ignore the error, or you post the entire exception message so that we can help you solve the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) when sending mail over SSL you should use port 465 i.e.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Port = 465;
...
```

You should probably still wrap the call to `Send` in a try/catch block and handle any `SmtpException` that gets thrown if you can do anything about it.

Note you can also put smtpClient configuration in the web.config file (see [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx) for example).

Comment: +1 beat me to it! :-) Yes, the port must be set correctly, that's most likely the issue

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the port number for Gmail which is 587.

```
smtp.port = 587;
```

And your problem should be solved.  Otherwise your code looks good.